# Populate HTML table with Vue 3

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I want to populate the table with the data I am getting back from my API. Now, the table is not displaying any data but I am retrieving and seeing the data in my `console.log`. Am I calling the data to my table wrongly?

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>S/N</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Group Role</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div></div></td>
        <td><div contenteditable>{{users}}</div></td>
        <td><div contenteditable>{{email}}</div></td>
        <td><div contenteditable>{{role}}</div></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
import { onMounted, ref, reactive } from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'manage-users-edit',

  setup(){
    const users = ref(null);
    const email = ref(null);
    const role = ref(null);
    const API_URL = '';

    async function getData() {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL);
      const data = await response.json();
      for(let i=0; i<=data.length; i++){
        users[i] = data[i].userName;
        email[i] = data[i].emailAddress;
        role[i] = data[i].userType;
        console.log('users', users[i]);
        console.log('email', email[i]);
        console.log('role', role[i]);
      }
    }

    onMounted(async () => {
      console.log('Dashboard mounted!')
      getData();
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return any data the template will use from `setup`.  Use an object whose property names match the template's variable names:

```js
setup() {
  ...
  return {
    users,
    email,
    role
  }
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```js
setup() {
  ...
  return {
    users: users,
    email: email,
    role: role
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `v-for` directive.
I would do the following for you :

```
...
setup(){
    let listUser = [] // It is better to go on a let since we will reassign the API data to the variable
    const API_URL = '';

    async function getData() {
       const response = await fetch(API_URL);
       const data = await response.json();
       this.listUser = data
       console.log('data-users', this.listUser);
  }
}
...
}
```

Then at the Template level, we browse all the data recorded in `listUser` using the `v-for` directive :

```
  ...
  <tr v-for="item in listUser">
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable>{{item.users}}</div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable>{{item.email}}</div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable>{{item.role}}</div></td>
  </tr>
  ...
```